# MacBook keeps automatically joining certain wifi network

Tags: network, wifi, tethering

My (12-inch retina) MacBook periodically joins a wrong wifi network, ignoring the preferred networks list in network preferences. (I'm using the latest version of Yosemite)

The wifi network is a 'special' network, it's my ISP's hotspot. After connecting to the network I am shown a pop-up asking to log in using my ISP login credentials. This is quite annoying.

I keep manually deleting the network from the list. But when I'm on the go, I often have to join the hotspot. I would simply like my MacBook to ignore the network whenever I'm at home.

Things I have tried so far:

1. Moving the 'bad' network to the bottom of the preferred networks list
2. Moving the 'bad' network to the top of the list (you never know, right? Haha)
3. Deleting all keychain entries related to the hotspot (it ignores those, I always have to re-enter the credentials in the pop-up window anyway)

Is there a solution to this problem? Or should I write a simple Apple or bash script which periodically deletes the hotspot from the known networks list?

---

**Edit:**

As requested by user [unknowndomain](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/6465/unknowndomain) below, here is some additional info.

At home I never want my computer to connect to the hotspot, only when on the road. (they are spread around the country). My home network is always on. It happens in other people's houses as well, my MacBook seems at certain times to prefer the hotspot ignoring other known ('higher priority') networks. I have the same problem with my old MacBook and with my girlfriend's MacBook Air so it's definitely a software related problem.

Some details of my home network 'Den Draad' and the hotspot 'TELENETHOMESPOT'.

[image: Home network details] [image]

Comment: It's a little strange that after moving it to the top of the list that it is still not respecting your preference. Do both networks have the same name or something? Could you provide a little more detail on the setup of whats happening?

Comment: Added some network details of my home network and the hotspot. They definitely don't have the same name.

Comment: I see, so your seeing the latter when you are away and at Home, thats why it is happening. Does the Den Draad network turn on and off? If you loose connection it will connect to the other one then it won't reconnect to yours unless you set it to.

Comment: Bit confusing to me. So you do connect to that network when on the road, but do not want to connect to it when at a home ?

Comment: That's correct. At home I never want my computer to connect to the hotspot, only when on the road. (they are spread around the country). My home network is always on, @unknowndomain. But it happens in other people's houses as well, my MacBook seems to prefer the hotspot no matter what (have the same problem with my old MacBook and with my GF's MacBook Air)

Comment: Ok, you have the TeleNethomespot router/modem.  That broadcasts  two WiFi signals. One is private the other is public. See some instructions here http://www.telenethomespot.be/portal/settings/en/index.html and more here http://www.telenethomespot.be/portal/info/en/index.html. Since you stay signed in in Telenet your Wifi will randomly choose which one to connect to once at home (close to your router) since both signals have same strength.  The only option you have is to disable the keep me signed in on the start up screen, which will result in you having to sign in when on the road.

Comment: I am not sure why it's doing this, but I think @Buscar웃SD is right, you might have to just deal with it or disable it. I don't suppose you can test this issue with another Mac to confirm it's an OS bug vs specific to your installation.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD. Yeah it must be related the the public / private signal, you're right. The weird things is both networks have a different BSSID, so the hotspot must be from a neighbor's router. Weird how OS X decides to periodically join the hotspot even if it has a lower 'priority' (using the preferred networks list)

Comment: It does not strictly obey the priority list (it is more interested in providing you a connection). If you look at your first screen shot, it shows you connected to your private Wifi, but it also shows the TeleNet as free wifi at about same signal strength. Those are the pro and con of the TeleNet system, but I love the Moules Frites when in your part of the world.